# HTTP post array merging with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, http, post

I have the following question:

I have the following inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" ...
<input type="text" name="qty[]" ...
<input type="text" name="value[]" ...
```

What I receive after posting is:

```
'name' => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => string 'Book One' (length=8)
    1 => string 'Book Two' (length=8)
    2 => string 'Book Three' (length=10)
'qty' => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => string '1' (length=1)
    1 => string '3' (length=1)
    2 => string '1' (length=1)
'value' => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => string '10' (length=5)
    0 => string '30' (length=5)
    0 => string '25' (length=5)
```

Because of that I cannot really do a foreach, and doing it with for and with the index is not a nice way. :(

I would like merge it into:

```
'items' =>
  array (size=3)
    0 => array('name' => 'Book One', 'qty' => '1', 'value' => '10')
    1 => array('name' => 'Book Two', 'qty' => '3', 'value' => '30')
    2 => array('name' => 'Book Three', 'qty' => '1', 'value' => '25')
```

Any nice way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still run an foreach on your array

```
$r = array(
    'name' => array (
        0 => 'Book One',
        1 => 'Book Two',
        2 => 'Book Three'
    ),
    'qty' => array(
        0 => '1',
        1 => '3',
        2 => '1'
    ),
    'value' =>  array(
        0 => '10',
        1 => '30',
        2 => '25'
    )
);

$i=0;
$e=array();
$ehh = array_keys($r);
foreach ($r as $k) {
    $e[] = array_combine($ehh, array_column($r,$i));
    $i++;
}


echo "<pre>";

print_r($e);

echo "</pre>";
```

$r is yr array, then $ehh stores it's keys for a while. Each loop takes corresponding column and combines it with key values. Product:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Book One
            [qty] => 1
            [value] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Book Two
            [qty] => 3
            [value] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Book Three
            [qty] => 1
            [value] => 25
        )

)
```

If yr < php 5 , array column function is not there yet, so use this:

```
function array_column($a=null,$b=null,$c=null){$argc=func_num_args();$d=func_get_args();if($argc<2){trigger_error("array_column() expects at least 2 parameters, {$argc} given",E_USER_WARNING);return null;}if(!is_array($d[0])){trigger_error('array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, '.gettype($d[0]).' given',E_USER_WARNING);return null;}if(!is_int($d[1])&&!is_float($d[1])&&!is_string($d[1])&&$d[1]!==null&&!(is_object($d[1])&&method_exists($d[1],'__toString'))){trigger_error('array_column(): The column key should be either a string or an integer',E_USER_WARNING);return false;}if(isset($d[2])&&!is_int($d[2])&&!is_float($d[2])&&!is_string($d[2])&&!(is_object($d[2])&&method_exists($d[2],'__toString'))){trigger_error('array_column(): The index key should be either a string or an integer',E_USER_WARNING);return false;}$e=$d[0];$f=($d[1]!==null)?(string) $d[1]:null;$g=null;if(isset($d[2])){if(is_float($d[2])||is_int($d[2])){$g=(int) $d[2];}else{$g=(string) $d[2];}}$h=array();foreach($e as $i){$j=$k=null;$l=$m=false;if($g!==null&&array_key_exists($g,$i)){$l=true;$j=(string) $i[$g];}if($f===null){$m=true;$k=$i;}elseif(is_array($i)&&array_key_exists($f,$i)){$m=true;$k=$i[$f];}if($m){if($l){$h[$j]=$k;}else{$h[]=$k;}}}return $h;}
```

or: from a comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) by robbieaverill[at]gmail.com //shorter function

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key, $return) {
  $value = $value[$return];
}, 'foo');
```